# Keras dataset has different vector length for train and test sets

Tags: python, list, keras, dataset, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use the reuters and imdb datasets from `keras.datasets`. The standard call is:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                  num_words=None,
                                                  skip_top=0,
                                                  maxlen=None,
                                                  seed=113,
                                                  start_char=1,
                                                  oov_char=2,
                                                  index_from=3)
```

When I check into the dimensions, the train dataset gives (25000, 10922), which makes good sense. But test gives (25000,). if you dump out individual test dataset elements like `x_test[0]`, it gives a list instead of `numpy.array`. The trouble is the list dimension changes for each row, and is always different from the train vector dimension. How are you supposed to use this as test data?

Comment: I am guessing maybe the test list is just the word indices without frequency?

Comment: I get a shape of `(25000,)` both for the train and the test datasets

Comment: @bhomass Was anything ambiguous in my answer or didn't it help?

Comment: yes, you are right. There was a line which I overlooked. x_train = np.array([np.bincount(doc, minlength=V) for doc in x_train])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you mentioned, each element in `x_train` and `x_test` is a list. That list contains words' indices of a sentence (or a paragraph or in this case a review) and since sentences may have different number of words, this corresponding representation also have variable length. Let's decode one of the sentences to see what it looks like and become more familiar with the dataset:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

# a mapping from words to their indices, for example `human`: 403
word_index = imdb.get_word_index()

# create the reverse mapping i.e. from indices to words
rev_word_index = {idx:w for w,idx in word_index.items()}

def decode_sentence(s):
    # index 0 to 2 are reserved for things like padding, unknown word, etc.
    decoded_sent = [rev_word_index.get(idx-3, '[RES]') for idx in s]
    return ' '.join(decoded_sent)

print(decode_sentence(x_train[100]))
```

which outputs the selected review in human-readable form:

> [RES] i am a great fan of david lynch and have everything that he's
>   made on dvd except for hotel room the 2 hour twin peaks movie so when
>   i found out about this i immediately grabbed it and and what is this
>   it's a bunch of [RES] drawn black and white cartoons that are loud and
>   foul mouthed and unfunny maybe i don't know what's good but maybe this
>   is just a bunch of crap that was [RES] on the public under the name of
>   david lynch to make a few bucks too let me make it clear that i didn't
>   care about the foul language part but had to keep [RES] the sound
>   because my neighbors might have all in all this is a highly
>   disappointing release and may well have just been left in the [RES]
>   box set as a curiosity i highly recommend you don't spend your money
>   on this 2 out of 10

The usage of this data entirely depends on you and the problem you are trying to solve. You can feed the sentences as it is to a network which can handle sentences with variable length. That usually consists of 1D-convolution layers or LSTM layers or a mix of both. One other approach is to make all the sentences to have the same length by encoding them to a fixed-length encoding. Here is an example that one-hot encodes each of the sentences to a vector of 0s and 1s with a fixed length for all the sentences:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
import numpy as np

# you can limit the vocabulary size by passing `num_words` argument 
# to ignore rare words and make data more manageable
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

def encode_sentences(sentences, dim):
    encodings = np.zeros((len(sentences), dim))
    for idx, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        encodings[idx, sentence] = 1.0
    return encodings

x_train = encode_sentences(x_train, 10000)
x_test = encode_sentences(x_test, 10000)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
```

which outputs:

```
(25000, 10000)
(25000, 10000)
```

All the sentences have been encoded to a vector of length 10000 where the i-th element of that vector indicates that whether the word with index `i` is present in the corresponding sentence or not.

Another approach is to truncate or pad sentences to make them the same length. Here is an example:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras import preprocessing

n_feats = 10000   # maximum number of words we want to consider in our vocabulary
max_len = 500     # maximum length of each sentence (i.e. truncate those longer
                  # than 500 words and pad those shorter than 500 words)

# you can limit the vocabulary size by passing `num_words` argument
# to ignore rare words and make it more manageable
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=n_feats)

# preprocess the sequences (i.e. truncate or pad)
x_train = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=max_len)
x_test = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=max_len)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
```

which outputs:

```
(25000, 500)
(25000, 500)
```

Now all the 25000 sentences have the same length and are ready to be used.

I highly recommend to read [the Keras documentation on this dataset](https://keras.io/datasets/#imdb-movie-reviews-sentiment-classification).

Comment: thanks, the selection of parameter values in the example made it harder to understand the behavior of the data set.